# Hair is not visible in Object mode (Cycles and Eevee) - Blender 2.82b

Tags: particles, hair

On Windows 10 in object mode strands have become invisible, but still renderable in render mode. On my working iMac everything is fine with the same blender file

In particle edit mode children hairs are not visible too.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to fix it by switching to Eevee and selecting Strand instead of Strip, and switching back to Cycles

[image]